# Extracting images from pdf using java

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have been trying to extract images from a pdf using pdfbox, converting them into buffered image and saving them.

```
 document = PDDocument.load("path");
        List pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        Iterator iter = pages.iterator();
        while( iter.hasNext() )
        {
            PDPage page = (PDPage)iter.next();
            PDResources resources = page.getResources();
            Map images = resources.getImages();
            if( images != null )
            {
                Iterator imageIter = images.keySet().iterator();
                int i = 0;
                while( imageIter.hasNext() )
                {
                    i++;
                    String key = (String)imageIter.next();
                    PDXObjectImage image = (PDXObjectImage)images.get( key );
                    BufferedImage b = image.getRGBImage();
                    File outputfile = new File("D:\\Image\\A"+i+".png");
                    ImageIO.write(b, "png", outputfile);
                }
            }
        }
```

but while converting into buffered image getRGBImage function is returning null. i need buffered image because i need to compare it with another image. how to solve this?

Comment: What version are you using? Were there any log messages? (If yes, please work them into the question) Can you upload the PDF somewhere? Try also the ExtractImages.java example. (My main suspicion is that you're missing the JBIG2 plugin)

Comment: I am using pdfBox version 1.6.0.  After executing this line " BufferedImage b = image.getRGBImage() " the value of b still remains null and hence image cannot be writen.

Comment: Please use the current version, 1.8.9

Comment: i was able to extract images from a coloured pdf. but while using black and white images i am still getting buffered image as null.